# VBA Error Code- 800A01A8 : Object required': 'Selection

Tags: vba, excel

I am getting this error while running this vba code. its kind of syntax error. Please help me with that. here is the script.
What script doing is , its copying data from one column to another and selecting the copied column.

```
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.Visible = True

Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\pc\Report\report_20120912.xls")
Set ws = objWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")
Set SelRange = objExcel.Selection
ws.Range("F2:F1000").AdvancedFilter 2,,ws.Range("M2"),True

ws.Range("N1") = ws.Range("A1")
ws.Range("O1") = ws.Range("B1")


//Below line has the bug

ws.Range("M2").Select             
selection=objExcel.Selection
col1=selection.End(xlDown)         //showing error on this line      
ws.Range(selection,col1).Select
n = ws.Range.Count
ws.Range("S2").Select
```

Comment: Why not totally take `Selection` out of your code? Directly work with the range? See this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/excel-macro-avoiding-using-select

Comment: Lemme know if you need an example?

Comment: @SiddharthRout : Thanks for you reply, would be good if you explain with an example. i went through the link provided by you above. What i want to do is selecting the column M from M2 cell till last say M1000.

Comment: @SiddharthRout : Does the same code example which you provided works well with VBA also.

Comment: I am sorry I do not understand what you mean? That is VBA Code. Are you doing this from VBA Excel?

Comment: @SiddharthRout:- Sorry i misunderstood something. It worked. Thanks a lot for your quick help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that you have tagged the question as Excel/Excel-VBA

If you are doing this in VBA Excel then you do not need to use `CreateObject` to create another instance of Excel. You can work with the current instance as well

See this code

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim objWorkbook As Workbook, ws As Worksheet

    Set objWorkbook = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\pc\Report\report_20120912.xls")
    Set ws = objWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")

    With ws
        '
        '~~> Rest of the code
        '
    End With
End Sub
```

As mentioned in my comment, throw the `Selection` / `Select` out of your code. It not only slows down your code but can also give you runtime errors. See this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/excel-macro-avoiding-using-select). I have commented the code below so that you will not have any problem understanding it. :)

Your above code can also be written as (*I have not tested the code*)

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim objWorkbook As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long, n As Long
    Dim mRange As Range

    '~~> Open the workbook
    Set objWorkbook = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\pc\Report\report_20120912.xls")
    '~~> Set the sheet that you want to work with
    Set ws = objWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")

    With ws
        .Range("F2:F1000").AdvancedFilter 2, , .Range("M2"), True

        .Range("N1").Value = .Range("A1").Value
        .Range("O1").Value = .Range("B1").Value

        '~~> Find the last row
        lRow = .Range("M" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        '~~> Set your range
        Set mRange = .Range("M2:M" & lRow)

        n = mRange.Count
    End With
End Sub
```

If you notice that you actually do not need to use `.Select` or work with the `Selection`

Answer (score 0):

The `Selection` property on `Application` is an object, so you need to use `Set` to assign it. Change

```
selection=objExcel.Selection
```

to

```
Set selection=objExcel.Selection
```

and the next line should work.

Comment: after putting the Set, its throwing the ""unknown runtime error.

Answer (score 0):

The following line is suspicious:

```
selection=objExcel.Selection
```

`selection` is probably supposed to be the global `Selection` propery (of `Application`). But you cannot assign to it; it's read-only. The spelling with the lower case `s` indicates that Excel is confused here. Furthermore, you would need to use `Set` to assign an object.